# Implementing my own Exercising Helper App - Collections consideration

Tags: java, android, collections

I'm trying to implement my own Exercise App for using at the gym.

I Bumped into a doubts which collection will fit to me the most.

SO, the class using the collection called "Exercise" 
and it has 3 variables, as described:

```
public class Exercise {

private String description;
private Map<Double, Integer> WeightsNRep;
private char category;

public Exercise(String description, char category){
    this.description=description;
    WeightsNRep = new HashMap<>();
    this.category = category;
}
```

as you can see, it hold three variables which one of them is description, and the interesting one is the WeightsNRep - Which needs to hold the data of each set - that means it will hold the WeightOFSet1,NumberOFRepInSet1, WeightOFSet2,NumberOFRepInSet2, ... till exercise will finish.

I have several requirements from the collection:

1. I can choose how many sets to do - it can be 4 or 5 or 3 depending on the exercise.
2. secondly, I want it to be readable since I want to store the data afterwards in a file with this template:

   "Description : " + Description + \t + **WeightOFSet1** + \t + **NumberOFRepInSet1**  + \t + ..... "

   till the final rep - and by that I mean that I want to iverride the toString fucntion but still I want the internal variables of the collection to be accessible nicely.

For example - as I choose HashMap I understood that if I set the key as my weights that's Would not be true since :

1. if I would have the same weights twice in one set, it would not save the second one - since Hashmap saves only one set for one key!
2. I would not be able to save that in order since I can just use the function get that accepts a key to get it's value.

Comment: "secondly, I want it to be readable" No out-of-the-box collection will do this for you, at least not in the specific format you describe. Whatever structure you choose, you will end up building that string yourself, so that's more or less a non-requirement.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @AndyTurner I Know That. I thought of override the to string fucntion, but still in that I want the internal variables to be accessible nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class called something like `RepSet`:

```
class RepSet {
  double weight;
  int reps;

  // Constructor (and any getters that may be required) omitted for brevity.
}
```

and store a list of these in the `WeightsNRep` field.

```
private List<RepSet> WeightsNRep = new ArrayList<>();
```

By using a list, you allow there to be multiple `RepSet`s for the same weight.

As for the requirements on the string: you just have to build that manually. For example:

```
"Description : " + Description
    + WeightsNRep.stream().map(r -> r.weight + "\t" + r.reps).collect(joining("\t"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Map with the weight as the key then the weight must be unique (because it's the key) for each set. You should consider using an object with the weight and reps of each set and put it on a List, if the order matters to you a LinkedList and if not an ArrayList.